# NiFi getHTTP or invokeHTTP which processor to use?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have following two scenario and for each one  I need recommendation as to which NiFi processor to use:

1. I have Restful web services running outside NiFi. NiFi would like to get/post/delete/update some data by calling specific restful API. Once the Restful API receives request from NiFi it sends back the response to NiFi. Which NiFi processor to use here?
2. In 2nd scenario, I have an application running outside NiFi. This application has its own GUI. The user need some information so he want to send request to NiFi. In NiFi, is there any processor which accepts request from application, process the request, and sends response back?

I actually read all the question with getHTTP and invokeHTTP.

I have initially tried with invokeHTTP processor. I tried both get and post call using invokeHTTP. But I don't see any response from Restful API running outside NiFi.

I did not try getHTTP.

I am using NiFi. NiFi do not have code.

I expect NiFi should be able to call Restful API running outside. I expect NiFi should accept request coming from application running outside and process that request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, NiFi comes bundled with processors that satisfy both of your requirements.

1. For scenario #1, you can use either a combination of `GetHTTP`/`PostHTTP` which as their name implies are HTTP clients that make `GET` and `POST` calls respectively. However, later the community came up with `InvokeHTTP` that offers more features like support for NiFi Expression Language, support for incoming flowfiles, etc.,
2. For scenario #2, you can either use `ListenHTTP` or the combination of `HandleHttpRequest`/`HandleHttpResponse`. The later literally offers you have a more robust web-service implementation while the former is a simple web-hook kind. I haven't worked much with `ListenHTTP` so probably can't comment more on that.

Having said that, for your second scenario, if your objective is to consume NiFi statistics, you can directly hit NiFi's rest api, rather than having a separate NiFi flow with web service capability.

**Useful Links**

- https://pierrevillard.com/2016/03/13/get-data-from-dropbox-using-apache-nifi/
- https://dzone.com/articles/using-websockets-with-apache-nifi
- https://ddewaele.github.io/http-communication-with-apache-nifi/

Comment: note: the `GetHTTP` does not allow an incoming relationship.